# Is it possible to make a sinatra application into a Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, sinatra, integrity

I'm considering using Integrity as a continuous integration tool, but don't want to (or can't) set up a separate domain for the application.

Is it possible to get a Sinatra app (like  integrity), and make it a Rails Engine? How would one go about do it?

EDIT: I realize that the "engines" normally require Rails code like controllers and views.

Bernie

Comment: Turns out using/understanding Rack is the best alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a blog article of someone who's done it [Pratik Naik's blog entry on Rails and Sinatra in the same process](http://m.onkey.org/2008/11/10/rails-meets-sinatra)

Answer (score 1):

As both Sinatra and recent Rails are Rack-based applications, I believe it's both more practical and simpler to integrate them using the specially baked rackup files.

As a variation on a solution provided by Ryan above, [here is a bit cleaner alternative](http://bit.ly/19bYmP) using config.ru file for Sinatra and Rails. And you can read more about rack and it's use in Rails on the official RoR guides website.

Comment: With this solution how would you specify the routes that go to the Rails app vs Sinatra app?